# Is there a way to create an empty sum type object whose actual type will be specified later in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
type NetworkState =
  | NetworkLoadingState
  | NetworkFailedState
  | NetworkSuccessState;

class NetworkLoadingState {}
class NetworkFailedState {}
class NetworkSuccessState {}

var a = new NetworkLoadingState(); // this is ok
var b = new NetworkState(); // I don't know the actual type of b yet, this doesn't compile

// I want to later do
b = new NetworkFailedState();
```

```
'NetworkState' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Is there a way to create an empty sum type object whose actual type will be specified later in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use union type as a constructor like in `F#` :)

You can only explicitly define a type for `b`.

```js
type NetworkState =
  | NetworkLoadingState
  | NetworkFailedState
  | NetworkSuccessState;

class NetworkLoadingState { }
class NetworkFailedState { }
class NetworkSuccessState { }

var a = new NetworkLoadingState(); // this is ok
var b: NetworkState; // ok

// I want to later do
b = new NetworkFailedState(); // ok
```